# HerokuiInstallation success but could be found

Tags: heroku

I am following this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxmxNeED4sk&list=PLx-q4INfd95G-wrEjKDAcTB1K-8n1sIiz&index=6 to install the heroku to run the sample django project

I am installing the Heroku by using pipenv install django-Heroku and it shows success, but when I try to run 'heroku create YourExpenseApp' it shows heroku not found as

```
(expensewebsite) (base) shihaomiao@shihaomiaodeMacBook-Air expensewebsite % pipenv install  django-heroku 
Installing django-heroku...
Adding django-heroku to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (abda51)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
(expensewebsite) (base) shihaomiao@shihaomiaodeMacBook-Air expensewebsite % heroku create YourExpenseApp 
zsh: command not found: heroku
```

I tried installing different Django versions like 3.0.4 3.2.12 but none of them worked, and now no idea how to install heroku by pipenv

Here is my setting.py:

```
import os

import django_heroku

"""
Django settings for expensewebsite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-+d(mbu1_a%##eox(=ei3mpn#=*5_$mz8@+3tg_ig9zjq+10hw3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'expensewebsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'expensewebsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'expensewebsite/static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

django_heroku.settings(locals())


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Here is the Pipfile
[

```
[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "==4.0.4"
psycopg2 = "==2.9.2"
gunicorn = "*"
npm = "*"
django-heroku = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

structure of project:

```
(expensewebsite) (base) shihaomiao@shihaomiaodeMacBook-Air expensewebsite % tree
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── db.sqlite3
├── expense
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── expensewebsite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   │   ├── dashboard.css
│   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   │       └── main.js
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── staticfiles
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── expense
│   │   ├── add_expense.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── newbase_verify.html
│   ├── partials
│   │   └── sidebar.html
│   └── verification
│       ├── login.html
│       ├── register.html
│       ├── resetPassword.html
│       └── setNewpassword.html
└── verification
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Comment: "no idea how to install heroku by pipenv"—because that's not how to install the Heroku CLI. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli, and also the description from that video: "Step 1. Download and Install The Heroku CLI from https://...".

Comment: And don't use [`django_heroku`](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku), which has been abandoned. Use [`django-on-heroku`](https://pypi.org/project/django-on-heroku/) instead.